# Rspec-rails doesn't seem to find my models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying out rspec, and immediately hit a wall when it doesn't seem to load db records I know exist. Here's my fairly simple spec (no tests yet).

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../spec_helper')

describe SomeModel do

  before :each do
    @user1 = User.find(1)
    @user2 = User.find(2)
  end

  it "should do something fancy"
end
```

I get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, saying it couldn't find User w/ ID=1 or ID=2, which I know for a fact exist. I set both test and development databases to point to the same schema in database.yml, so this shouldn't be database mixup. I also ran `script/generate rspec` after installing the gems (rspec, rspec-rails), and gem.config both environment.rb and test.rb. Any idea what I'm missing? thanks.

**EDIT**

Seems I was running the tests with `rake spec:models`, which emptied the db and thus no records were found. When I used `% spec spec/models/some_model_spec.rb`, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't RSpec expect fixtures to be set? I also so rspec_model generators, but I don't know if those are needed for what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should not* be relying on test data to be there in your database, as it could (and often does!) change. Secondly, you *should not* be joining your test and development database at the same database. Tests *should* run on a pure database, not one corrupted by your development mucking about.

What you *should* be doing is setting up data specifically for the tests in the form of fixtures, or by using a tool such as [factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or [machinist](http://github.com/notahat/machinist).